# How to get the longest "overlapping" words

Tags: sql, oracle

**Premise**: Suppose you have a table containing words, where some may be distinct and some "*may overlap*", meaning a longer word starts with a shorter one, eg:

```
---------------
|    word     |
---------------
| dog         | *
| games       | *
| stat        |
| state       | 
| statement   | *
| fulfill     |
| fulfilled   | *
| fulfillment | *
---------------
```

**Question**: How does one write a query that returns the list of non-overlapping + the longest overlapping words in such cases?

In the example above, the desired words are identified by a `*`, as per the following extended explanation:

- `dog` and `games` don't overlap with anything, so they're the longest in their *"solo/distinct"* category
- `statement` overlaps with `state` and `stat` and is the longest
- `fulfilled` overlaps with `fulfill` and is longer *(does NOT overlap with `fulfillment`)*
- `fulfillment` overlaps with `fulfill` and is longer *(does NOT overlap with `fulfilled`)*

**Note**: Please be aware that for the sake of simplicity, the data sample is reduced. In reality there are a few million records to query and, there are no search terms known before hand, so it's not possible to directly use constructs such as `WHERE word LIKE 'stat%'`. Not sure if relevant or not, but the words have a relatively short max length, eg 20.

Comment: Overlap means only prefix-match or any substring?

Comment: @astentx longer word starts with smaller one, so prefix only. However please note that we're talking "_whole word prefix_", please see the `fulfill`, `fulfilled` & `fulfillment` example

Comment: Can there be duplicates (same word appearing multiple times in the column)? If so, do you need DISTINCT results? Separately, can the "word" be NULL?

Comment: @mathguy no `NULLs`. As for duplicates I presume yes, I'm not the owner of the table (actually a materialized view), it's _"externally managed"_ so I have to assume the worst and ignore duplicates.

Comment: Hopefully the column is indexed (which is supported for materialized views, but often ignored).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you compare prefixes and if one word is entirely included as prefix of the other, you may try `match_recognize` to sequentially check prefix-matching in one pass.

But `exists` is more clear, though you should examine performace on your real dataset with index on `word`.

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     column_value as word
>   from sys.odcivarchar2list(
>     'dog'
>     , 'games'
>     , 'stat'
>     , 'state'
>     , 'statement'
>     , 'fulfill'
>     , 'fulfilled'
>     , 'fulfillment'
>   )
> )
> select *
> from a 
> match_recognize(
>   order by word desc /*Longest first*/
>   measures
>     a.word as word
>   one row per match
>   /*Exclude any number of words
>     each of which is a prefix of the previous one
>   */
>   pattern (a {- b* -})
>   define
>     /*Current word is a prefix of the previous*/
>     b as prev(word) like word || '%'
> ) t
> ```
>
> ```
> | WORD        |
> | :---------- |
> | statement   |
> | games       |
> | fulfillment |
> | fulfilled   |
> | dog         |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=20466d7e075e828adb1473a0fc7b1158)*

Comment: In the pattern, the `a` doesn't need to be optional (in every match there will always be at least one row, and that will automatically be classified as `a`). If the column is indexed, `match_recognize` may take advantage of that (so there's no overhead for the ORDER BY step), in which case this may work faster than the anti-join. It will be interesting if the OP tries both solutions and lets us know what he observes. I may also test it myself - if I do I will let you know the results.

Comment: @mathguy Thank you a lot for the clarification as I'm not so familiar with this clause. Fixed. Unfortunately I have no local Oracle installation for test, but it will be interesting to compare.

Comment: @astentx a bit off-topic perhaps, nonetheless, FYI in case you needed something like this and didn't know it existed, I use a docker container based on the [gvenzl/oci-oracle-xe](https://github.com/gvenzl/oci-oracle-xe) image for local tests.

Comment: @astentx, really cool solution using `match_recognize`. you have my vote ;) . Although I think fulfilled should not appear in the list

Comment: @RobertoHernandez `fulfilled` should definitely be in the list as per the OP extended description: it's longer than `fulfill` and there is no other bigger word containing it

Comment: @Morfic, you are right. My mistake, I understood it differently.

Comment: I ran tests - please see the results under MT0's answer. `match_recognize` is about 2.5 times faster than my anti-join solution. I only tested with the existence of an index on `word` - I will try without an index next (which will hurt all solutions, but it's interesting to see which will be hurt most).

Comment: OK - without index, the `match_recognize` runs just a tiny bit slower (0.75 seconds), but the anti-join solution becomes much slower (over 30 seconds, after which I just stopped it). So this is hands-down the best solution in Oracle 12.1 and higher.

Comment: @mathguy interestingly enough on my end I have different results. On a 1mil data-set, retrieving pages of 1k items, with an index, your query is the fastest with 0.3s while astentx's & marmite bomber's solutions execute roughly in the same time frame of 0.6s. Without an index, the 2 still keep a similar trend of 0.7-0.8s while yours did not finish after ~3m (moment in which I killed it).

Comment: @Morfic I think the `lag` version does nearly the same as `match_recognize` because it can also be processed sequentially after sorting (and executed plan shows similar resource usage, though I didn't trace them both to check internals). Index lookup may also benefit from parallelization: it doesn't require sync point (sorting), so can perform lookups in multiple processes simultaneously

Answer (score 6):

Something like

```
select word
from   your_table t1
where  not exists (
                    select word
                    from   your_table t2
                    where  t2.word like t1.word || '_%'
                  )
;
```

The query would benefit from the existence of an index on `word`. But even then it may take a long time. In any case, you can give it a try and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 2):

> How does one write a query that returns the list of non-overlapping + the longest overlapping words in such cases?

You can do it in a single table scan with a hierarchical query:

```sql
SELECT word,
       MAX(PRIOR word) AS substring
FROM   words
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1
AND    LEVEL IN (1,2)
CONNECT BY word LIKE PRIOR word || '%'
AND        PRIOR ROWID != ROWID
GROUP BY word;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE words (word) AS
SELECT 'dog' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'games' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'stat' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'state' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'statement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'fulfill' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'fulfilled' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'fulfillment' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | WORD | SUBSTRING |
> | --- | --- |
> | dog |  |
> | games |  |
> | statement | state |
> | fulfilled | fulfill |
> | fulfillment | fulfill |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=82620f7d3424ae521b6fea86612db74c)*

---

#### Update

You can also get the longest sub-string match using `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`:

```sql
SELECT word,
       substring
FROM   words
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  ORDER BY word DESC
  MEASURES
    PREV(word.word) AS prev_word,
    word.word AS word,
    substring.word AS substring
  ONE ROW PER MATCH
  AFTER MATCH SKIP TO NEXT ROW
  PATTERN (word (non_substring*? substring)?)
  DEFINE
    substring     AS word.word LIKE word || '_%'
)
WHERE  prev_word IS NULL
OR     prev_word NOT LIKE word || '%'
```

Which, for the sample data, gives the same output as above.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f93a92c3ced68d4cca0ac30edb241f66)*

Comment: Thanks, interesting approach, especially the hierarchical one. However, with all due respect, I feel it's either incomplete or I must be missing something, because I don't see how the produced output matches the expected one described in the OP. Instead of returning each word and their "_substring/ancestor_" as it does now, it should return the "_distinct/solo_" words, plus the longest in each overlapping "_category_": `dog`, `games`, `statement`, `fulfilled`, `fulfillment`.

Comment: @Morfic Updated.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to do so, this is definitely an interesting solution.

Comment: @Morfic - The need to `GROUP BY WORD` at the end makes this a very inefficient (exceptionally slow) solution when there is a lot of data. I just tested on a table with 800,000 rows; the `match_recognize` solution is fastest at 0.6 seconds, the anti-join solution is next at 1.6 seconds, while the `connect by` solution is still running (and I will probably stop it) - it's been running for more than ten minutes already. Note also that `connect by` must read data more than once (it's just sugarcoated syntax for self joins), it's not superior because "it reads the data just once".

Comment: However, it does return the maximum substring. If you don't do that then you can eliminate the aggregation so you aren't comparing like-for-like. But, yes, for just a list of words, use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE`.

Comment: Right. I will re-write the query so it only returns what the OP asked, not any extraneous stuff.

Comment: Changed to the code attached at the end, and I still had to stop it after several minutes. Post a better version if you can find one. Here is what I tried: `select word from your_table where connect_by_isleaf = 1 and level = 1 connect by word like prior word || '_%' and level <= 2`

Comment: @mathguy thank you for the heads-up. I didn't get the chance to start testing yet (calls & etc, you know...). For now I'm trying to learn what goes beyond each solution (not a DBA here) and eventually do the tests. For this one for example, I think I can `CONNECT BY MSISDN || '_%'` (or leave in `PRIOR ROWID != ROWID`) then drop the `max & group by`, and return just the level 1 leaves, essentially having: `SELECT word FROM words WHERE CONNECT_BY_ISLEAF = 1 AND LEVEL = 1 CONNECT BY word LIKE PRIOR word || '_%';`. Either way, thank you all 3 for your time and effort, I've learned a lot today.

Comment: This is elegant solution, but fails with `ORA-01436: CONNECT BY loop in user data` in case of a duplicated word ( e.g. twice `fulfillment`).

Comment: @MarmiteBomber There are many solutions for that including `CONNECT BY word LIKE PRIOR word || '_%'` or `CONNECT BY word LIKE PRIOR word || '%' AND word > PRIOR word` .... or just adding `NOCYCLE`.

Answer (score 2):

You may simple **sort** the words and discard all *words* that are the *prefix* of the  *following* word.

You must consider the last word (see the `OR` predicate in the `where` condition)

```
with words as (
select WORD,
lead(WORD) over (order by WORD) WORD_LEAD
from tabs )
select word 
from words
where word != substr( WORD_LEAD, 1, length(word)) or WORD_LEAD is NULL /* last word */
order by word;
```

result

```
WORD 
-----------
dog
fulfilled
fulfillment
games
statement
```

This solution covers the *duplicates* as well and does not contains the prohibitive `FILTER` operation as other proposals that would trottle the performance for large tables (except for the `match_recognize`solution).